# Applying Lebesgue’s DCT to prove that finite E|X| implies continuous differentiability

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

I'd like to ask about bringing the derivative inside the expected value.

The context is proving that if $\mathbb{E}X < \infty$, then $\mathbb{E}X = \frac{1}{i}\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi_X(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}|_{t = 0}$. It is the first proposition [here](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-probability/characteristic-function) where $n = 1$. The argument begins with

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi_X(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} &= \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{E}e^{itX}}{\mathrm{d}t} \\
&= \mathbb{E}\frac{\mathrm{d}e^{itX}}{\mathrm{d}t}.
\end{align}
$$

I see various references mention Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem. I'm trying to use the notation from slide 3 [here](https://pages.stat.wisc.edu/%7Eshao/stat609/stat609-07.pdf):

$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow y_0}\int h(x, y)\mathrm{d}x = \int \lim_{y\rightarrow y_0}h(x, y)\mathrm{d}x,
$$

where $h$ satisfies appropriate conditions.

What is $h$ when bringing the derivative inside the expected value? My attempt for absolutely continuous $X$:

$$
\begin{align}
h(x, t) &= \frac{e^{i(t + y)x} - e^{itx}}{y}. \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathbb{E}e^{itX} &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\int e^{itx}f_X(x) \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{\int e^{i(t + y)x}f_X(x) \mathrm{d}x - \int e^{itx}{f_X}(x) \mathrm{d}x}{y} \\
&= \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\int \frac{e^{i(t + y)x} - e^{itx}}{y}f_X(x) \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\int h(x, t)f_X(x) \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{i(t + y)x} - e^{itx}}{y}f_X(x) \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}e^{itx}f_X(x) \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \mathbb{E}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} e^{itX},
\end{align}
$$

but then how do you bound $|h|$?

Comment: $|h(x,t)|\le |x|$.

Comment: You can use the fundamental theorem of calculus to write the difference quotient as an integral of the derivative. Bounding the difference quotient can then be done by bounding the derivative.

Comment: @Mason $h(x, t) = \frac{ix}{y}\int_{t}^{t + y}e^{iux}du$ so $|h(x, t)| \leq |x|$, but |x| isn't integrable. Am I using the wrong $h$?

Answer (score 0):

Including the density in $h$ allows the application of $\mathbb{E}|X| < \infty$.